# How add and view my events on google calendar into android application?

Tags: java, android, google-calendar-api

It's simple using GData, but GData doen't work on Android :(
I only need add and view events, searching many days and nothing...
I know, there are many topics on stackoverflow with it but I can't find clearly and simply solution. Can somebody give me a simply examples?
Sorry for my language and problem - I'm begginer :(

Regards,
Thomas

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need [Google APIs Client](http://code.google.com/p/google-api-java-client/), it works fine on Android.